# Create a XML Decoder from a string or byte array GO

Tags: xml, go

I have a xml decode function in my app and I use xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body) to decode my xml. the NewDecoder functions receives an io.Reader. But the problem is that in my response from the server I receive the first 230 bytes i need to ignore and the remaining bytes are the xml encoded in base64 that I want to decode. Here an example of the response body:

```
    --RandomCaracteres...
    Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8; name=response_xml

    <Response success="1"/>
    --RandomCaracteres...
    Content-Type: text/xml; name=report.xml
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    PE5leHBvc2VSZXBvcnQgdmVyc2lvbj0iMi4wIj4KPHNjYW5zPgo8c2NhbiBpZD0iNDYwMCIgbmFt......
```

I need to read only the PE5leHBvc2VSZXBv... data. With the following code I can read the xml:

```
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(bodyBytes)[230:])
    fmt.Println(data)
```

but I can't call the xml.NewDecoder() function because data is not a io.Reader type. Is there any way to creade a Decode object from a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes there is](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader):

```
r := strings.NewReader(dataStr)
```

[And likewise for byte arrays](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader):

```
r := bytes.NewReader(dataBytes)
```

Or, using bytes, you can skip the `Reader` and `NewDecoder` entirely and just use [`Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) directly:

```
err := xml.Unmarshal(dataBytes, &myobj)
```

Or with a `string`, cast and use `Unmarshal`:

```
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(dataStr), &myobj)
```

Comment: Isn't unmarshal slow for huge xml files? I choose the decode function because it is faster

Comment: Nope. The only way `Decode` is any faster than `Unmarshal` is when you can use `Decode` to stream data rather than loading all of it into memory at once. Since you already have all of it in memory, there is no advantage to be had.

Comment: In fact, if you [look at the implementation of `Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/read.go?s=5406:5454#L116), all it does is wrap the input in a `bytes.Reader`.